# Filtering against the URL (REST framework)

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework

i want to pass data from url in view.
i read [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) and try to write!
but i got a error :

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

serializer.py :

```
class ContactsDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = ('id', 'profile_id', 'tel','email')
```

views.py:

```
class ContactsDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request ):
        queryset = Contacts.objects.all()
        serializer = ContactsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py:

```
  router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register(r'profiles', views.ProfileViewSet)
    # router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
    router.register(r'members', views.MemberViewSet)
    router.register(r'files', views.FilesViewSet)
    router.register(r'contacts', views.ContactsViewSet)
    router.register(r'products', views.ProductsViewSet)
    router.register(r'stories', views.StoriesViewSet)

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
        url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
         url(r'^test', ContactsDetailsViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),//here
        url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    ]
```

anybody can help? how to pass data(by REST framework) ?

Comment: try this for the url pattern: `'^test/(?P<profile_id>[0-9]+)/$'`

Comment: i checked but does'nt work @Bitonator

Comment: ah, found the problem, 'as_view()' is missing, it should be `views.ContactsDetailsViewSet).as_view()` in the urlpatterns

Comment: Sorry, but does'nt work @Bitonator

Comment: sorry, just realized, '.as_view()' should come before the closing bracket, it should be `views.ContactsDetailsViewSet.as_view())`

Comment: i know it man! i tried. trust me. it does'nt work!

Comment: You need to use `ContactsDetailsViewSet.as_view()` as Bitonator mentioned. What error do you get when you try that?

Comment: the error no change! this is : __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given @knbk

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

```
url('^test/(?P<profile_id>.+)$', views.ContactsDetailsViewSet),
```

You need to call the `as_view()` with the mappings. This isn't a regular view, it's a [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example):

```
url('^test/(?P<profile_id>.+)$', views.ContactsDetailsViewSet).as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})),
```

Also note that you'll need to specify `profile_id` as `lookup_url_kwarg`.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback otherwise it's just guesswork.